# how to get an element property in advance (not when I call a function)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's a bit of code for something, like a carousel.
The problem is I can't switch to the 2nd card when I first press the Right arrow. I think it's because the function doesn't know that cardStack **left** property equals -20px. But when I add this bit of code, `var l = cardStack.left;`, into a function, it works fine. But afaik it's not a good idea to mention `document.` every time I call a function. I need your advice

```js
var cardStack = document.getElementById('allCards');
var l = cardStack.left;

document.onkeydown = cardsShifting;

function cardsShifting(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      shiftCard('left');
      break;
    case 39:
      shiftCard('right');
      break;
  }
}

function shiftCard(direction) {
  if (direction === 'right') {
    l = l - 640;

    if (l >= -5780) {
      cardStack.style.left = l + 'px';
    } else {
      l = -20;
      cardStack.style.left = l + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#allCards {
  position: relative;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#currentCardWindow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 420px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="currentCardWindow">
  <div id="allCards">
    <div class="card">card 1</div>
    <div class="card">card 2</div>
    <div class="card">card 3</div>
    <div class="card">card 4</div>
    <div class="card">card 5</div>
    <div class="card">card 6</div>
    <div class="card">card 7</div>
    <div class="card">card 8</div>
    <div class="card">card 9</div>
    <div class="card">card 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `cardStack.style.left` you're not actually looking at the CSS but rather at the style attribute on the element. Fortunately, there is a way to look at the CSS! We can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

> The `window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

With this you can do `window.getComputedStyle(cardStack)` to get all the CSS styles and then on to that you can add `getPropertyValue("left")` to just look at the `left` property. This returns `-20px` but we want to ignore the px we can do this with `parseInt`.

I've put it all together in this snippet.

```js
var cardStack = document.getElementById('allCards');
var l = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cardStack).getPropertyValue("left"));

document.onkeydown = cardsShifting;

function cardsShifting(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      shiftCard('left');
      break;
    case 39:
      shiftCard('right');
      break;
  }
}

function shiftCard(direction) {
  if (direction === 'right') {
    l = l - 640;

    if (l >= -5780) {
      cardStack.style.left = l + 'px';
    } else {
      l = -20;
      cardStack.style.left = l + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#allCards {
  position: relative;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#currentCardWindow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 420px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="currentCardWindow">
  <div id="allCards">
    <div class="card">card 1</div>
    <div class="card">card 2</div>
    <div class="card">card 3</div>
    <div class="card">card 4</div>
    <div class="card">card 5</div>
    <div class="card">card 6</div>
    <div class="card">card 7</div>
    <div class="card">card 8</div>
    <div class="card">card 9</div>
    <div class="card">card 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you find this helpful.